# Most concise way to group pairs of elements in an array with jq

Tags: jq

I want to convert

```
[1,"a",2,"b",3,"c"]
```

to

```
[[1,"a"],[2,"b"],[3,"c"]]
```

The best I've come up with is (using 1.5)

```
[recurse(.[2:];length>1)[0:2]]
```

Is there a more concise or more performant or 1.4 compatible solution I could use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would have tried to do something like you did, to me that feels right from a functional perspective.

But there are other ways this could be expressed.  You could take advantage of the fact that when converting an array to entries, you get an array of index/value pairs.

```
to_entries | group_by(.key/2 | floor) | map(map(.value))
```

On the other hand, you could also just create slices of the array using a range of numbers.  I think this may perform better than recursing.

```
. as $arr | [ range(0; length/2) * 2 | $arr[.:.+2] ]
```

Comment: The second approach is efficient and much to be preferred to the first.

Answer (score 1):

The following generalizes the task, works with jq 1.4, is highly performant with the optimizations in jq 1.5, and can be used to implement rho/1 (like R's "dim(z) <- c(3,5,100)" and APL's "A⍴B"):

```
# Input: an array
# Output: a stream of arrays
# If the input is [] then the output stream is empty,
# otherwise it consists of arrays of length n, each array consisting
#  of successive elements from the input array, padded with nulls.
def takes(n):
  def _takes:
    if length == 0 then empty
    elif length < n then .[n-1] = null
    else .[0:n], (.[n:] | _takes)
    end;
  _takes;
```

Using "takes", one could fulfill the task using: *[takes(2)]*

Using "rho", there are several possibilities, notably:

```
[rho( [ 2 ] )]

# or:

rho([3,2])
```

For more about "rho", see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/829

Comment: Do you know if the processor does tail call optimizations or handles slicing efficiently? I haven't worked with large enough data sets to notice any performance optimizations.

Comment: jq has had some really important TCO since July 1 2014.  It can make a huge difference.  See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Advanced-Topics#recursion-and-tail-recursion-optimization for details.

Comment: Ah, very useful, did not know about that page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most concise way but here is a solution using **foreach** to gather and emit pairs of values.

```
[
  foreach .[] as $x (
      []                                  # init
    ; if length>1 then [] else . end      # update
      | . + [$x]
    ; if length>1 then  . else empty end  # extract
  )
]
```